# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed - неизвестная мне ошибка

Tags: python, discord, бот

Вчера не было такого, решил с утра придумать что-то новое для бота, а когда запустил его появилась ошибка, везде пишут включить интенты на developers портале дискорда, но они уже были включены.
Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 563, in connect
    self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 481, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 306, in from_client
    socket = await client.http.ws_connect(gateway)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 132, in ws_connect
    return await self.__session.ws_connect(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 769, in _ws_connect
    raise WSServerHandshakeError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.WSServerHandshakeError: 503, message='Invalid response status', url=URL('wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=6&compress=zlib-stream')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\bot\main.py", line 285, in <module>
    bot.run("ТУТ ТОКЕН БОТА")
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 612, in connect
    ws_params.update(sequence=self.ws.sequence, resume=True, session=self.ws.session_id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sequence'
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000157AC5C9790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Добавил сегодня только этот код, чтобы затестить вообще отправку личных сообщений.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def send(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.send('test')
```

Comment: Что именно вы добавили (код) сегодня.

Comment: Отредактировал сообщение и добавил код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На днях сталкивался с [такой же проблемой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110528/python-discord-runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed-when-launched-from-a-specific).

Попробуйте подключиться к другой сети и запустить. Например, использовать телефон как модем. Если все будет работать, то перезапустите роутер и проблема должна решиться (если у вас динамический IP).