# Discord.py. RuntimeError: Event loop is closed. Ошибка появилась внезапно

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Использую библиотеку Discord.py с начала 2021-го года. Все было хорошо, но сегодня при попытки запустить код бота (client.run(TOKEN)), происходит ошибка.

Вот трассировка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 563, in connect
    self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 479, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 306, in from_client
    socket = await client.http.ws_connect(gateway)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 132, in ws_connect
    return await self.__session.ws_connect(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 733, in _ws_connect
    raise WSServerHandshakeError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.WSServerHandshakeError: 503, message='Invalid response status', url=URL('wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=6&compress=zlib-stream')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Колаж\Код\Прогеры\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 612, in connect
    ws_params.update(sequence=self.ws.sequence, resume=True, session=self.ws.session_id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sequence'
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001FA6C6664C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 751, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001FA6C6664C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 751, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

В редких случаях, и не понятно почему - ошибка не случается, и бот нормально запускается, но в большинстве случаев все таки происходит эта ошибка.

(Уже пробовал):

1. Менял токены бота.
2. Ставил галочки на PRESENCE INTENT и SERVER MEMBERS INTENT в Discord DEVELOPER PORTAL.
3. Переустанавливал библиотеки.
4. Ошибка явно не в моем коде, потому-что раньше этот же код запускался нормально и без ошибок

Comment: Ошибка у вас в коде, менять токены и ставить галочки тут бесполезно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [RuntimeError: Event loop is closed - неизвестная мне ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407520/runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Проверку на ошибки я сделал в первую очередь, и тем-более раньше этот же код запускался нормально.

Comment: Это всё никак не гарантирует отсутствия ошибок у вас в коде

Answer (score 0):

Я сталкивался с такой же ошибкой и также создавал тему [RuntimeError: Event loop is closed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407520/runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Мне ответили, что ошибка может быть связана с интернет соединением. Я не менял код несколько дней и это оказалось единственным вариантом, перезагрузка роутера мне помогла, попробуйте и вы.